# Using ECT template with Chaplin

Tags: chaplinjs

Hello I want to use ect templates with the Chaplin js. I am not able to integrate the ect template the way Handlebar is integrated as per Chaplin boiler plate.Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way for this you just need to **override** the render function as per the syntax of the ect template in your application base view class.
I did it in this way

```
render : function() {
    var $templateHtml, html, templateFunc;
    if (this.disposed) {
      return false;
    }
    var data = { message : 'Hello, World!' };
    html = ECT({ root : 'js/templates' }).render(this.templateName,data)
    if (!this.noWrap) {
       this.$el.html(html);
    } 
    else {
       $templateHtml = $(html);
       if ($templateHtml.length > 1) {
         throw new Error('There must be a single top-level element when ' + 'using `noWrap`.');
       }
       this.undelegateEvents();
       this.setElement($templateHtml, true);
    }
    return this;
}
```